# Very soon, my PhD starts in UK but UK visa center in Paris is closed. What should I do?

Tags: united-kingdom, france, uk-visa, covid-19

I am a non-EU citizen, currently residing in France. I am supposed to start a PhD on december the 1st in UK. I completed the VISA application and paid all the realted fees (NHS + application fees) just to finally discover that the VISA center in Paris is closed due to Covid-19 and as a result I can't make an appointment. All other centers are open in Europe except in France. I feel very unlucky and troubled by this unfortunate situation. Is there any possible solution or hope for my case?

Comment: Do you actually need to be physically present at the University? Most classes would be online now.

Comment: Have you followed the detailed instructions found at:  [Welcome to TLScontact: IMPORTANT: COVID-19 IMPACT](https://pos.tlscontact.com/par_en/)? Customers affected can [contact us](https://pos.tlscontact.com/par_en/contact/) for queries .... [Applying for a visa if your VAC is closed](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-advice-for-uk-visa-applicants-and-temporary-uk-residents)

Comment: @JonathanReez my French residence permit does not allow me to work full time on a job offered in a fogein country and my home country is currently border-closed due to Covid since quite a while :/.

Comment: @MarkJohnson thanks for the links but I have already checked them out and nothing's interesting. TLScontact contact page is completely useless. the gov.uk site is also not very helpful in this regard. I wanted to call TLScontact in Paris but I couldn't find their phone number anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: Studies may not be considered a Job. You should ask about that (if possible).

Comment: Have you contacted the university you're supposed to attend? Its Foreign Students Office is very likely to have seen this issue before.

Comment: @JonathanReez the OP is talking about a PhD.  That's a *research* degree not taught (though there may be some classes early on)/

Comment: ... Similarly (@MarkJohnson) UK postgrad studies are complicated regarding employment: students aren't employees of the university, but they may well be receiving money from it (a stipend) or from another funding body if an overseas student

Comment: @ChrisH The topic was about taking part online while in **France** and whether a special french permit would be needed for that.

Comment: @MarkJohnson located in France, **enrolled in a UK university**.  The latter is very relevant. The OP would have to convince the French authorities that they're not employed despite them quite possibly having a stipend mentioned on the confirmation of their UK place (assuming studying is allowed, that is).

Comment: @MarkJohnson I was on a research contract that sponsored my current residence permit in France and now it's finished and in few months I will have to move out. I am supposed to move to the UK for my PhD but this Covid-19 is making everything slow and complicated. Borders closed, VISA centers closed, flights suspeded, I really have no idea how to move on with my life with all those crazy restrictions.

Comment: @ChrisH moreover, it's really full of bureaucraccy here and things taking at least 1 or 2 months to get sorted out. I don't really want to bother too much, especially that everything is closed now, even administrations. I just want to move out and start my research as peaceful as possible.

Comment: Which country are you from? Almost every country in the world can now be reached by a citizen of that country.

Comment: As explained in the links provided above, if you find another centre in the Schengen Area you should be able to apply there and go there for biometrics etc. Not the easiest of tasks these days, of course, but better than nothing. Depending on where you are, the easiest option may be Brussels, Düsseldorf, Geneva, Milan or Barcelona, for instance (I haven’t checked if they’re actually open or if there are entry restrictions into those countries which would prevent you from getting there or force you to quarantine).

Comment: Thanks @jcaron. Unfortunately, I might not be able as I have already made the application selecting the Paris center. I have to cancel first but I expect it to take a lot of time before I get the refunds, so I think I will have to wait and hope for the best (but apprently, Itsn't and it won't :v).

Comment: The UK government page says you can re-apply at another centre (and pay again) and ask for a refund at the original centre. So it’s a cash flow issue, but you are (currently) able to submit your application to another centre even if your have already submitted an application. Of course there’s always the risk that additional restrictions could be set in the other countries preventing you from getting there as well :-(